# align div text and div background image/div image right?

Tags: html, css

Hi i was wondering if it was possible to align the text and an image inside a div to the right? because the text inside the div will change and read out the name of each members profile name on my site, at the moment when i try and do it the text overlaps the image?

```
.prof-content-box-left-lower {
    /* [disabled]height: 200px; */
    /* [disabled]position: relative; */
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    z-index:90;
```

Comment: Show us your HTML code and make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can look at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably just want to make the image float right.  See the inline CSS on the image tag in this example.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .prof-content-box-left-lower {
                /* [disabled]height: 200px; */
                /* [disabled]position: relative; */
                margin-top: 25px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-right: 18px;
                width: 200px;
                position:relative;
                text-align:right;
                z-index:90;
                background: #CCCCCC;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "prof-content-box-left-lower">
            <img src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" style = "float: right" width = 100 height = 100>
            my example text
            <div style = "clear: both"></div> <!-- this line clears the float so you can stack these divs, which I expect you probably will-->
        </div>
        <div class = "prof-content-box-left-lower">
            <img src = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" style = "float: right" width = 100 height = 100>
            my example text
            <div style = "clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```